# CLUTO doc2mat specified stop word list not working

Tags: perl, nlp, document, data-mining, stop-words

I am trying to convert my documents into vector-space format using [doc2mat](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/files/fs/sw/cluto/doc2mat.html)

On the website, it says I can use my specified text file where words are white-space separated or on multiple lines. So, I use some code similar to this one:

`./doc2mat -mystoplist=stopword.txt -skipnumeric mydocuments.txt myvectorspace.txt`

However, when I check the output `.clabel` file, it still has stop words that's in `stopword.txt`.

I really do not know how to do this. Someone help me out please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one important thing I should remember: I should include ALL the unwanted words in my stop list. This is somewhat difficult since there's always some variations available...

For example, if I want to exclude `method` I add it to my list. However, the resulting vocabulary may also contain `method` since there are words like `methodist`, `methods`, etc. Then doc2mat by default stems these words and I will still get `method` in the output.

Another thing is to make sure that "-nostop" option must be provided for user-specified stop list.